# Could not start ZK at requested port of 2181, while export HBASE_MANAGES_ZK=false

Tags: linux, hadoop, hbase, zookeeper, cloudera

**Problem**

The first aim was to run HBase standalone. Navigating to ip:60010/master-status is succesfull once HBase has been started.

The second aim is to run a distinct ZooKeeper quorum. ZooKeeper has been downloaded and has been started:

```
netstat -nato | grep 2181
tcp        0      0 :::2181                     :::*                        LISTEN      off (0.00/0/0)
```

The `conf/hbase-env.sh` was changed as follows:

```
# Tell HBase whether it should manage it's own instance of Zookeeper or not.
export HBASE_MANAGES_ZK=false
```

in order to avoid HBase starts ZooKeeper once HBase has been started.

However, the following error occurs once HBase has been started.

```
Could not start ZK at requested port of 2181.  ZK was started at port: 2182.  
Aborting as clients (e.g. shell) will not be able to find this ZK quorum.
```

**Question**

How to disable the startup of ZooKeeper by HBase and run ZooKeeper separately?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According to [this documentation](http://hbase.apache.org/book/standalone_dist.html) the `/usr/lib/hbase/conf/hbase-site.xml` file needs to be configured as follows:

```
<configuration>
  <property>
    <name>hbase.cluster.distributed</name>
    <value>true</value>
  </property>
</configuration>
```

to avoid HBase manages its own ZooKeeper.

After configuring this, the `zookeeper-server` and `hbase-master` were started independently.